# How to implement ripple effect on recycler view item when it enters action mode via long press

Tags: android

Currently, when I long press on a recycler view item, the app will enter action mode. This is how I implement such feature.

### WatchlistArrayRecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
@Override
public WatchlistArrayRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                                   int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    final View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.watchlist_row_layout, parent, false);

    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(view);

            if (actionMode) {
                toggleSelection(position);
                v.setActivated(selectedItems.get(position, false));
            }

            recyclerViewOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, position);
        }
    });

    v.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            int position = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(view);

            if (!actionMode) {
                toggleSelection(position);
                v.setActivated(selectedItems.get(position, false));
            }

            recyclerViewOnItemClickListener.onItemLongPress(view, position);

            return true;
        }
    });

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}
```

### WatchlistFragment.java

```
@Override
public void onItemLongPress(View childView, int position) {
    if (actionMode != null) {
        return;
    }

    actionMode = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).startSupportActionMode(new AnActionModeOfEpicProportions());
    watchlistArrayRecyclerViewAdapter.setActionMode(true);

    updateTitle();
}
```

### watchlist_linear_layout_selector_material_light.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/watchlist_row_layout_selected_color_material_light">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/watchlist_linear_layout_selector_for_ripple_material_light"/>
</ripple>
```

### watchlist_linear_layout_selector_for_ripple_material_light.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/watchlist_row_layout_selected_color_material_light" />

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/watchlist_row_layout_selected_color_material_light" />   <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/watchlist_row_layout_selected_color_material_light" />  <!-- selected -->

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/watchlist_row_layout_normal_color_material_light" />
</selector>
```

This is how it looks like when I perform long press.

https://youtu.be/2biPlMwlmkk

---

***However, when I look at WhatsApp, I realize at the moment the app enters action mode, there will be another ripple effect. It looks as following***

https://youtu.be/1PuRAv-DfWs

May I know, how can I achieve such effect?

Comment: test `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"` in `recycleView` tags.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan RecyclerView does not use that attribute.

Comment: @Cheok Just because WhatsApp does it does not mean you must do it also. We also have no way to know if WhatsApp is using the same things you are (maybe they have a `ListView` instead of a `RecyclerView`).